# Width depending on child element's width and content height

Tags: html, css, css-float, shape-outside

I want to create an angled text flow where the width of a text line is a known value `--w`. What I have so far is the code below:

```css
* { margin: 0 }

html, body { display: grid }

body {
  --w: min(35em, 65vw);
  --f: 1/ 8;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent var(--w), pink 0);
  font: 1em ubuntu, sans-serif
}

.outer-wrapper {
  width: min-content;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px red;
  background: lemonchiffon
}

span::before, span::after {
  --i: 0;
  --j: calc(1 - var(--i));
  --g: 
    linear-gradient(to right bottom, 
        hsla(50, 50%, 50%, var(--j)) 50%, 
        hsla(50, 50%, 50%, var(--i)) 0);
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: var(--f);
  background: var(--g);
  shape-outside: var(--g);
  content: ''
}
span::after {
  --i: 1;
  float: right
}

.inner-wrapper {
  width: var(--w);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px blue
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <p>Gingerbread macaroon cake topping wafer cake dessert. Lemon drops cheesecake lemon drops lollipop biscuit tart. Chupa chups bonbon dragée tart pie. Oat cake cupcake bear claw pie ice cream ice cream. Jelly beans ice cream icing halvah cotton candy. Tiramisu dragée macaroon chocolate bar chocolate cake. Sweet roll wafer candy gummies donut wafer liquorice sugar plum. Icing gummies chocolate cake gummies caramels sweet roll. Tootsie roll jelly beans jelly chocolate jelly beans pie. Halvah lollipop lemon drops shortbread bonbon. Jelly biscuit bear claw cotton candy cotton candy chocolate bar soufflé donut lollipop. Fruitcake lemon drops marshmallow sugar plum cheesecake gingerbread. Sugar plum chupa chups candy canes jelly-o powder liquorice icing.</p>
    <p>Gingerbread macaroon cake topping wafer cake dessert. Lemon drops cheesecake lemon drops lollipop biscuit tart. Chupa chups bonbon dragée tart pie. Oat cake cupcake bear claw pie ice cream ice cream. Jelly beans ice cream icing halvah cotton candy. Tiramisu dragée macaroon chocolate bar chocolate cake. Sweet roll wafer candy gummies donut wafer liquorice sugar plum. Icing gummies chocolate cake gummies caramels sweet roll. Tootsie roll jelly beans jelly chocolate jelly beans pie. Halvah lollipop lemon drops shortbread bonbon. Jelly biscuit bear claw cotton candy cotton candy chocolate bar soufflé donut lollipop. Fruitcake lemon drops marshmallow sugar plum cheesecake gingerbread. Sugar plum chupa chups candy canes jelly-o powder liquorice icing.</p>
    <p>Gingerbread macaroon cake topping wafer cake dessert. Lemon drops cheesecake lemon drops lollipop biscuit tart. Chupa chups bonbon dragée tart pie. Oat cake cupcake bear claw pie ice cream ice cream. Jelly beans ice cream icing halvah cotton candy. Tiramisu dragée macaroon chocolate bar chocolate cake. Sweet roll wafer candy gummies donut wafer liquorice sugar plum. Icing gummies chocolate cake gummies caramels sweet roll. Tootsie roll jelly beans jelly chocolate jelly beans pie. Halvah lollipop lemon drops shortbread bonbon. Jelly biscuit bear claw cotton candy cotton candy chocolate bar soufflé donut lollipop. Fruitcake lemon drops marshmallow sugar plum cheesecake gingerbread. Sugar plum chupa chups candy canes jelly-o powder liquorice icing.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that I would like the floated pseudos on the sides to add to the `--w` width and make the `.outer-wrapper` wider by the width of one because otherwise, text overflows outside the red outline box.

[image: screenshot]

And I have no idea how to do that with CSS. I know it's possible with JS, I have a working version were I read the `px`-valued height, store it in a variable, update it on resize and compute all from there. But I'd really like to do it with just CSS.

Skewing the box is not a useful solution in this case.

Comment: I had the same issue when dealing with shape-outside and the 100% height here: https://css-tricks.com/hexagons-and-beyond-flexible-responsive-grid-patterns-sans-media-queries/ and here https://css-tricks.com/float-an-element-to-the-bottom-corner/ and I never found a solution due to "a cyclic dependency" but maybe it's time to give it another try

Answer (score -1):

It's not without its drawbacks and might not work for your specific use-case, but you could use a hidden copy of the content in a narrower container to determine the height you need, then use `height: 100%` to give `.outer-wrapper` the height it needs. Here's my code:

```
* { margin: 0 }

html, body { display: grid }

body {
  --w: min(35em, 65vw);
  --f: 1/ 8;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent var(--w), pink 0);
  font: 1em ubuntu, sans-serif
}

.outer-outer-wrapper {
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.height-setter {
  background: lightgreen;
  width: calc(var(--w) * (1 - var(--f)));
  visibility: hidden;
}

.outer-wrapper {
  width: min-content;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px red;
  background: lemonchiffon;
  height: 100%;
}

span::before, span::after {
  --i: 0;
  --j: calc(1 - var(--i));
  --g: 
    linear-gradient(to right bottom, 
        hsla(50, 50%, 50%, var(--j)) 50%, 
        hsla(50, 50%, 50%, var(--i)) 0);
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: var(--f);
  background: var(--g);
  shape-outside: var(--g);
  content: ''
}
span::after {
  --i: 1;
  float: right
}

.inner-wrapper {
  width: var(--w);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px blue;
}
```

```
<div class="outer-outer-wrapper">
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <p>Gingerbread macaroon cake topping wafer cake dessert. Lemon drops cheesecake lemon drops lollipop biscuit tart. Chupa chups bonbon dragée tart pie. Oat cake cupcake bear claw pie ice cream ice cream. Jelly beans ice cream icing halvah cotton candy. Tiramisu dragée macaroon chocolate bar chocolate cake. Sweet roll wafer candy gummies donut wafer liquorice sugar plum. Icing gummies chocolate cake gummies caramels sweet roll. Tootsie roll jelly beans jelly chocolate jelly beans pie. Halvah lollipop lemon drops shortbread bonbon. Jelly biscuit bear claw cotton candy cotton candy chocolate bar soufflé donut lollipop. Fruitcake lemon drops marshmallow sugar plum cheesecake gingerbread. Sugar plum chupa chups candy canes jelly-o powder liquorice icing.</p>
    <p>Gingerbread macaroon cake topping wafer cake dessert. Lemon drops cheesecake lemon drops lollipop biscuit tart. Chupa chups bonbon dragée tart pie. Oat cake cupcake bear claw pie ice cream ice cream. Jelly beans ice cream icing halvah cotton candy. Tiramisu dragée macaroon chocolate bar chocolate cake. Sweet roll wafer candy gummies donut wafer liquorice sugar plum. Icing gummies chocolate cake gummies caramels sweet roll. Tootsie roll jelly beans jelly chocolate jelly beans pie. Halvah lollipop lemon drops shortbread bonbon. Jelly biscuit bear claw cotton candy cotton candy chocolate bar soufflé donut lollipop. Fruitcake lemon drops marshmallow sugar plum cheesecake gingerbread. Sugar plum chupa chups candy canes jelly-o powder liquorice icing.</p>
    <p>Gingerbread macaroon cake topping wafer cake dessert. Lemon drops cheesecake lemon drops lollipop biscuit tart. Chupa chups bonbon dragée tart pie. Oat cake cupcake bear claw pie ice cream ice cream. Jelly beans ice cream icing halvah cotton candy. Tiramisu dragée macaroon chocolate bar chocolate cake. Sweet roll wafer candy gummies donut wafer liquorice sugar plum. Icing gummies chocolate cake gummies caramels sweet roll. Tootsie roll jelly beans jelly chocolate jelly beans pie. Halvah lollipop lemon drops shortbread bonbon. Jelly biscuit bear claw cotton candy cotton candy chocolate bar soufflé donut lollipop. Fruitcake lemon drops marshmallow sugar plum cheesecake gingerbread. Sugar plum chupa chups candy canes jelly-o powder liquorice icing.</p>
  </div>
</div>
  
  <div class="height-setter">
    <p>Gingerbread macaroon cake topping wafer cake dessert. Lemon drops cheesecake lemon drops lollipop biscuit tart. Chupa chups bonbon dragée tart pie. Oat cake cupcake bear claw pie ice cream ice cream. Jelly beans ice cream icing halvah cotton candy. Tiramisu dragée macaroon chocolate bar chocolate cake. Sweet roll wafer candy gummies donut wafer liquorice sugar plum. Icing gummies chocolate cake gummies caramels sweet roll. Tootsie roll jelly beans jelly chocolate jelly beans pie. Halvah lollipop lemon drops shortbread bonbon. Jelly biscuit bear claw cotton candy cotton candy chocolate bar soufflé donut lollipop. Fruitcake lemon drops marshmallow sugar plum cheesecake gingerbread. Sugar plum chupa chups candy canes jelly-o powder liquorice icing.</p>
    <p>Gingerbread macaroon cake topping wafer cake dessert. Lemon drops cheesecake lemon drops lollipop biscuit tart. Chupa chups bonbon dragée tart pie. Oat cake cupcake bear claw pie ice cream ice cream. Jelly beans ice cream icing halvah cotton candy. Tiramisu dragée macaroon chocolate bar chocolate cake. Sweet roll wafer candy gummies donut wafer liquorice sugar plum. Icing gummies chocolate cake gummies caramels sweet roll. Tootsie roll jelly beans jelly chocolate jelly beans pie. Halvah lollipop lemon drops shortbread bonbon. Jelly biscuit bear claw cotton candy cotton candy chocolate bar soufflé donut lollipop. Fruitcake lemon drops marshmallow sugar plum cheesecake gingerbread. Sugar plum chupa chups candy canes jelly-o powder liquorice icing.</p>
    <p>Gingerbread macaroon cake topping wafer cake dessert. Lemon drops cheesecake lemon drops lollipop biscuit tart. Chupa chups bonbon dragée tart pie. Oat cake cupcake bear claw pie ice cream ice cream. Jelly beans ice cream icing halvah cotton candy. Tiramisu dragée macaroon chocolate bar chocolate cake. Sweet roll wafer candy gummies donut wafer liquorice sugar plum. Icing gummies chocolate cake gummies caramels sweet roll. Tootsie roll jelly beans jelly chocolate jelly beans pie. Halvah lollipop lemon drops shortbread bonbon. Jelly biscuit bear claw cotton candy cotton candy chocolate bar soufflé donut lollipop. Fruitcake lemon drops marshmallow sugar plum cheesecake gingerbread. Sugar plum chupa chups candy canes jelly-o powder liquorice icing.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The potential issues are:

- The height isn't guaranteed to be correct due to line break locations. If it's acceptable for `.outer-wrapper` to be a little too big, you could add one or two extra lines to cover yourself by giving `.height-setter` 1 or 2 ems of bottom padding.
- You have duplicated content in your code (though I believe [screen readers won't see it](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-hide-text-from-screen-readers) so long as `visibility: hidden` is set).
- `.outer-outer-wrapper` is wider than the content displayed inside it. On my screen with your code this was fine, but in practice you might need some clever flex cropping or an `.outer-outer-outer-wrapper` with `overflow: hidden` set to get around this.

Comment: https://codepen.io/jonedge/pen/ZEMLJgx

Comment: I was not able to find any value that make your code works fine. It can only work in one or two particular case for a specific screen width.

Answer (score -1):

### Just pure CSS as asked

**Note: you have to place your contents twice in HTML code as below**

It is easy if you print your content using a dynamic language.

It works in every screen size. Size of the content doesn't matter and it can have paddings too.
You can also change `--f` and `--w` values and everything works too!

```css
* {
        margin: 0;
    }

    html, body { display: grid }

    body {
        --w: min(35em, 65vw);
        --f: 15%;
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent var(--w), pink 0);
        font: 1em ubuntu, sans-serif
    }

    .outer-wrapper {
        width: var(--w);
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px red;
        background: lemonchiffon;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }

    span::before, span::after {
        --i: 0;
        --j: calc(1 - var(--i));
        --g:
                linear-gradient(to right bottom,
                hsla(50, 50%, 50%, var(--j)) 50%,
                hsla(50, 50%, 50%, var(--i)) 0);
        float: left;
        height: 100%;
        width: var(--f);
        background: var(--g);
        shape-outside: var(--g);
        content: ''
    }
    span::after {
        --i: 1;
        float: right
    }

    .inner-wrapper {
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px blue
    }

    .inner-wrapper-hidden {
        width: calc(100% - var(--f));
        visibility: hidden;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .inner-wrapper-absolute {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
<div class="inner-wrapper-absolute">
    <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <p>Gingerbread macaroon cake topping wafer cake dessert. Lemon drops cheesecake lemon drops lollipop biscuit tart. Chupa chups bonbon dragée tart pie. Oat cake cupcake bear claw pie ice cream ice cream. Jelly beans ice cream icing halvah cotton candy. Tiramisu dragée macaroon chocolate bar chocolate cake. Sweet roll wafer candy gummies donut wafer liquorice sugar plum. Icing gummies chocolate cake gummies caramels sweet roll. Tootsie roll jelly beans jelly chocolate jelly beans pie. Halvah lollipop lemon drops shortbread bonbon. Jelly biscuit bear claw cotton candy cotton candy chocolate bar soufflé donut lollipop. Fruitcake lemon drops marshmallow sugar plum cheesecake gingerbread. Sugar plum chupa chups candy canes jelly-o powder liquorice icing.</p>
        <p>Gingerbread macaroon cake topping wafer cake dessert. Lemon drops cheesecake lemon drops lollipop biscuit tart. Chupa chups bonbon dragée tart pie. Oat cake cupcake bear claw pie ice cream ice cream. Jelly beans ice cream icing halvah cotton candy. Tiramisu dragée macaroon chocolate bar chocolate cake. Sweet roll wafer candy gummies donut wafer liquorice sugar plum. Icing gummies chocolate cake gummies caramels sweet roll. Tootsie roll jelly beans jelly chocolate jelly beans pie. Halvah lollipop lemon drops shortbread bonbon. Jelly biscuit bear claw cotton candy cotton candy chocolate bar soufflé donut lollipop. Fruitcake lemon drops marshmallow sugar plum cheesecake gingerbread. Sugar plum chupa chups candy canes jelly-o powder liquorice icing.</p>
        <p>Gingerbread macaroon cake topping wafer cake dessert. Lemon drops cheesecake lemon drops lollipop biscuit tart. Chupa chups bonbon dragée tart pie. Oat cake cupcake bear claw pie ice cream ice cream. Jelly beans ice cream icing halvah cotton candy. Tiramisu dragée macaroon chocolate bar chocolate cake. Sweet roll wafer candy gummies donut wafer liquorice sugar plum. Icing gummies chocolate cake gummies caramels sweet roll. Tootsie roll jelly beans jelly chocolate jelly beans pie. Halvah lollipop lemon drops shortbread bonbon. Jelly biscuit bear claw cotton candy cotton candy chocolate bar soufflé donut lollipop. Fruitcake lemon drops marshmallow sugar plum cheesecake gingerbread. Sugar plum chupa chups candy canes jelly-o powder liquorice icing.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="inner-wrapper-hidden">
    <p>Gingerbread macaroon cake topping wafer cake dessert. Lemon drops cheesecake lemon drops lollipop biscuit tart. Chupa chups bonbon dragée tart pie. Oat cake cupcake bear claw pie ice cream ice cream. Jelly beans ice cream icing halvah cotton candy. Tiramisu dragée macaroon chocolate bar chocolate cake. Sweet roll wafer candy gummies donut wafer liquorice sugar plum. Icing gummies chocolate cake gummies caramels sweet roll. Tootsie roll jelly beans jelly chocolate jelly beans pie. Halvah lollipop lemon drops shortbread bonbon. Jelly biscuit bear claw cotton candy cotton candy chocolate bar soufflé donut lollipop. Fruitcake lemon drops marshmallow sugar plum cheesecake gingerbread. Sugar plum chupa chups candy canes jelly-o powder liquorice icing.</p>
    <p>Gingerbread macaroon cake topping wafer cake dessert. Lemon drops cheesecake lemon drops lollipop biscuit tart. Chupa chups bonbon dragée tart pie. Oat cake cupcake bear claw pie ice cream ice cream. Jelly beans ice cream icing halvah cotton candy. Tiramisu dragée macaroon chocolate bar chocolate cake. Sweet roll wafer candy gummies donut wafer liquorice sugar plum. Icing gummies chocolate cake gummies caramels sweet roll. Tootsie roll jelly beans jelly chocolate jelly beans pie. Halvah lollipop lemon drops shortbread bonbon. Jelly biscuit bear claw cotton candy cotton candy chocolate bar soufflé donut lollipop. Fruitcake lemon drops marshmallow sugar plum cheesecake gingerbread. Sugar plum chupa chups candy canes jelly-o powder liquorice icing.</p>
    <p>Gingerbread macaroon cake topping wafer cake dessert. Lemon drops cheesecake lemon drops lollipop biscuit tart. Chupa chups bonbon dragée tart pie. Oat cake cupcake bear claw pie ice cream ice cream. Jelly beans ice cream icing halvah cotton candy. Tiramisu dragée macaroon chocolate bar chocolate cake. Sweet roll wafer candy gummies donut wafer liquorice sugar plum. Icing gummies chocolate cake gummies caramels sweet roll. Tootsie roll jelly beans jelly chocolate jelly beans pie. Halvah lollipop lemon drops shortbread bonbon. Jelly biscuit bear claw cotton candy cotton candy chocolate bar soufflé donut lollipop. Fruitcake lemon drops marshmallow sugar plum cheesecake gingerbread. Sugar plum chupa chups candy canes jelly-o powder liquorice icing.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's not really pure CSS because you have to duplicate the content which means that we cannot apply this solution to an existing content. I also think that using 2 lines of JS would be more efficient that duplicating the content of the whole page

Comment: You Just said No JS. It's not clean but there is no JS!

Comment: I said "only CSS". Duplicating the whole HTML is not "only CSS" even if you didn't use JS.

Answer (score -1):

One approach to solving this with pure CSS is using math to set the height of the `.outer-wrapper`. Let's solve a simple equation to get the new height in terms of the old height, width and aspect ratio.

We know that the area that the text occupies in both cases is the same i.e the shaded regions. We just need to increase that height of the `outer-wrapper` in proportion.

[image: Shaded regions]

[image]

I was not able to set the height as mentioned on `outer-wrapper` as I can't get the syntax right, any help to finish the problem will be much appreciated.

```
.outer-wrapper {
    width: min-content;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px red;
    background: lemonchiffon;
    height: calc((var(--w) + sqrt(var(--w) * var(--w) - 4 * var(--f) * var(--w)))/(2 * var(--f)));
}
```

Comment: The formula is not really a problem, the OP already know how to get it (and she already did) but the issue is how to get the values to use them. How to get the width to express the height OR how to get the height to express the width.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, The width doesn't change, so we can use the old width itself i.e `--w` and the height comes from the formula as a function of the width `--w`, old height `100%` and the aspect ratio `--f`. There are no other dependencies.